# Unpack format characters in Python

Tags: python, perl, unpack

I need the Python analog for this Perl string:

```
unpack("nNccH*", string_val)
```

I need the `nNccH*` - data format in Python format characters.

In Perl it unpack binary data to five variables:

- 16 bit value in "network" (big-endian)
- 32 bit value in "network" (big-endian)
- Signed char (8-bit integer) value
- Signed char (8-bit integer) value
- Hexadecimal string, high nibble first

But I can't do it in Python

More:

```
bstring = ''
while DataByte = client[0].recv(1):
    bstring += DataByte
print len(bstring)
if len(bstring):
    a, b, c, d, e = unpack("nNccH*", bstring)
```

I never wrote in Perl or Python, but my current task is to write a multithreading Python server that was written in Perl...

Comment: I can find the equivalent of everything except for H*, for which I would assume you would play with p or s.

Comment: You will need to calculate the string size, this answer could be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5849224/70350

Comment: `"while DataByte = client[0].recv(1):"` is not Python.  This can never work.

Comment: @SenthilKumaran: AFAIR `*` just means "as many elements as are left", so he can unpack everything before the `H*`, and then just grab the rest without unpack

Comment: By the way, Sir D, thanks for editing and clarifying the question. The last code snippet makes little sense though, as S.Lott noticed

Comment: See [**THIS**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867714/auto-repeat-flag-in-a-pack-format-string/49927071) question for how to repeatedly apply a format string!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Perl format `"nNcc"` is equivalent to the Python format `"!HLbb"`.
There is no direct equivalent in Python for Perl's `"H*"`.

There are two problems.

- Python's `struct.unpack` does not accept the wildcard character, `*`
- Python's `struct.unpack` does not "hexlify" data strings

The first problem can be worked-around using a helper function like `unpack`.

The second problem can be solved using `binascii.hexlify`:

```py
import struct
import binascii

def unpack(fmt, data):
    """
    Return struct.unpack(fmt, data) with the optional single * in fmt replaced with
    the appropriate number, given the length of data.
    """
    # http://stackoverflow.com/a/7867892/190597
    try:
        return struct.unpack(fmt, data)
    except struct.error:
        flen = struct.calcsize(fmt.replace('*', ''))
        alen = len(data)
        idx = fmt.find('*')
        before_char = fmt[idx-1]
        n = (alen-flen)//struct.calcsize(before_char)+1
        fmt = ''.join((fmt[:idx-1], str(n), before_char, fmt[idx+1:]))
        return struct.unpack(fmt, data)

data = open('data').read()
x = list(unpack("!HLbbs*", data))
# x[-1].encode('hex') works in Python 2, but not in Python 3
x[-1] = binascii.hexlify(x[-1])
print(x)
```

When tested on data produced by this Perl script:

```
$line = pack("nNccH*", 1, 2, 10, 4, '1fba');
print "$line";
```

The Python script yields

```
[1, 2, 10, 4, '1fba']
```

Comment: An alternative to `binascii.hexlify()` is `str.encode("hex")`.

Comment: If you want Python 3 compatibility, you'll need `//` when calculating `n`, otherwise `str(n)` produces '16.0' and breaks the format string.

Comment: In Python 3.4 and newer, there is `struct.iter_unpack`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49927071/3620003) is a demonstration.

Answer (score 7):

The equivalent Python function you're looking for is `struct.unpack`. Documentation of the format string is here: http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html

You will have a better chance of getting help if you actually explain what kind of unpacking you need. Not everyone knows Perl.

Comment: Thanks. I already read the perl and python unpack docs. But so far i don't understand some moments.

Comment: @Eli -there could minor trouble in direct translation. For e.g how would one do H* in python? I guess, the user could have worded the question better.

Comment: @SenthilKumaran: note that the user has edited the question *after* my answer. Before the edit he didn't lay out the meanings of the format chars in Perl

Comment: @SirD: "so far i don't understand some moments".  Please be **specific** on what you do not understand.  Please **update** the question to say what you do not understand.